# How can change marker position in react native maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

Hello I want to add a draggable marker on the map "change a position of marker-based on map views"
So I use react-native-maps,

when the user swipes the map and changes his location the marker following hem so in my code I log it in the console but I can't see anything in the logs or it's not made in this way!
How can I make it draggable on the map?

here is what I want to achieve
[image: map]

here's my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';

// create a component
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    latlng: {
      latitude: 35.1790507,
      longitude: -6.1389008,
    },
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          region={{
            latitude: 35.1790507,
            longitude: -6.1389008,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          }}>
          <Marker
            draggable
            coordinate={this.state.latlng}
            title="Home"
            onDragEnd={e => {
              console.log('dragEnd', e.nativeEvent.coordinate);
            }}
          />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    // height: 400,
    // width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

//make this component available to the app
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onRegionChangeComplete` property of `MapView` to achieve this.

First, change the state object like the following:

```
state = {
    markerData: {
      latitude: 35.1790507,
      longitude: -6.1389008,
    },
    mapData: {
      latitude: 35.1790507,
      longitude: -6.1389008,
      latitudeDelta: 0.015,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
    },
  };
```

Change your `MapView` accordingly.

```
<MapView
     style={{flex: 1}}
     region={this.state.mapData}
     onRegionChangeComplete={this.handleRegionChange}>
     <Marker
        coordinate={this.state.markerData}
        title="Home"
        onDragEnd={e => {
              console.log('dragEnd', e.nativeEvent.coordinate);
            }}
      />
</MapView>
```

Then define a handler function, which changes the state values when the user drags over the map:

```
handleRegionChange = mapData => {
    this.setState({
      markerData: {latitude: mapData.latitude, longitude: mapData.longitude},
      mapData,
    });
  };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great!! it's work :D if I want to add some smoothly animation to marker because it navigates from pose to pose quickly

Comment: There's a method for ```Marker``` called ```animateMarkerToCoordinate```, but unfortunately, it's for Android only.

Comment: yeah my target it's android now , how can i handle it with your code ?

Comment: See this: [Animated Marker Position](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps#animated-marker-position)